# Concatenate 3d tensors by cloning one tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 20, 100])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1, 100])
```

I want to append `b` to `a[i, 20, 100]`, to create `c` such as `c` has a shape of `[None, 20, 200]`.

This seems rather simple but I haven't figured out how to do this with `tf.concat`:

```
tf.concat(0, [a, b]) -> Shapes (20, 100) and (1, 100) are not compatible
tf.concat(1, [a, b]) => shape=(?, 28, 100) which is not what I wanted
tf.concat(2, [a, b]) -> Shapes (?, 20) and (?, 1) are not compatible
```

Do I need to reshape `a` and `b` first then concat?

Comment: You will need to use `tf.tile` before `tf.concat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#tile). You will need to *clone* the tensor along dimension 1, `20` times to make it compatible with `a`. Then a simple concatenation along dimension 2 will give you the result.

Here is the complete code,

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 20, 100])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1, 100])
c = tf.tile(b, [1,20,1])
print c.get_shape()
# Output - (?, 20, 100)
d = tf.concat(2, [a,c])
print d.get_shape()
# Output - (?, 20, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Actually if I dunno the 2nd dimension of `a` what do I do? i.e. `a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 100]); b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1, 100])`. `tf.tile` requires `int32/64` type for argument..

Comment: Solved by using `tf.unpack(tf.shape(a))[1]` ! :) Thanks again