# How to migrate NumPy preprocessing into a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow for machine learning on Ogg and MIDI data, but a lot of preprocessing is done in NumPy (with feed_dict:s), and I'd like to migrate as much of it as possible into the computational graph in order to simplify production deployment (Google Cloud ML, or maybe self-hosted TensorFlow Serving). How would I go about this? Are there ways of converting NumPy to TensorFlow operations automatically?

Comment: maybe `tf.py_func` is useful for you

Comment: The way to do it is to go over the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/) and find a matching TensorFlow variant for each numpy call. There's no automatic way of doing it, but sometimes the APIs match closely (ie, broadcasting, arithmetic operations)

Comment: _The tf.py_func() operation has the following known limitations:

The body of the function will not be serialized in a GraphDef. Therefore, you should not use this function if you need to serialize your model and restore it in a different environment._ [(reference)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/script_ops/script_language_operators_#py_func)

Comment: @CarlThomé So how *do* you serialize the fn?

Comment: Basically, you can't. There's two options: 1) deploy the Python code as well; 2) manually make sure all preprocessing is done with TensorFlow ops. For 1. I'd say https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines looks pretty alright for many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Numpy functions have their TensorFlow equivalent documented in [`array_ops`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/).
For the more mathematical operations, have a look at [`math_ops`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/).

Finally, if you have more specific queries or are unable to convert some Numpy code to TensorFlow, you should always try to search StackOverflow Q/A or ask a question here. (Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417692/concatenate-3d-tensors-by-cloning-one-tensor) for a good example of such a question).

---

Unrelated - If you face difficulties carrying out some matrix manipulation, try to look at the existing [Numpy Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) on StackOverflow. They can easily be applied to TensorFlow using the APIs above.

Comment: Manually porting code from one API to another seems like a pretty bad (and obvious) solution. Surely there will popup some tool eventually to transpile from NumPy to TensorFlow? Otherwise, I might be looking into creating such a compiler myself actually.

Comment: @CarlThomé, a lot depends on what you wish to leave as `Tensors` and what you wish to cache as `Variables`. Tensorflow functions aren't really equivalent to Numpy, but they will be in certain cases. Anyway, you are welcome to write your own answer here